# cant connect to my ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

just created an ec2 instance and can ssh into it and everything but when i go to either its elastic ip or its public DNS url I cannot it returns a page saying "Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to 23.23.205.241" I can also ping its public DNS but when i visit that url i also get a "Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to ec2-23-23-205-241.compute-1.amazonaws.com" message

I can successfully ping the ip address and get a response and i have the following security groups set up:
22   tcp    0.0.0.0/0
25   tcp    0.0.0.0/0
80   tcp    0.0.0.0/0
110  tcp    0.0.0.0/0
143  tcp    0.0.0.0/0
443  tcp    0.0.0.0/0
3306     tcp    0.0.0.0/0
8080 tcp    0.0.0.0/0
0-65535 udp 0.0.0.0/0
53   udp    0.0.0.0/0
-1   icmp   0.0.0.0/0

This instance is of type: Amazon Linux AMI 2012.09 64 bit.

I have just installed tomcat7 on it as well but i was unable to see my webpage before that installation.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Linux AMI does not include a web server by default, so you cannot see a web page at its address until you install and start a web server. You've done that with Tomcat now, and apparently you can now see the web page that Tomcat serves.

Comment: how can i see the web page that tomcat serves? I was expecting it to show up when i typed in the elastic ip address i assigned to my instance.

Comment: @user1103205 What port do you have Tomcat running on?  Typically default port would be 8080, so did you use the correct port in your URL (i.e. http://ec2-23-23-205-241.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080) ?

Comment: correct, i have tomcat running on port 8080. Didnt try to specify what port to connect to using the url but your link seems to give me the same error as without specifying the port number.

Comment: If the instance's public DNS name is `ec2-23-23-205-241.compute-1.amazonaws.com`, for example, and you're running Tomcat on port 8080, the URL to connect would be `http://ec2-23-23-205-241.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/`.

Comment: Ah, and im guessing its just in the wrong location so when i use the elastic ip address i have associated with my instance it cannot find doesnt display any site at all?

Any chance you know the default location i should put my index.html file in a Amazon Linux AMI 2012.09 64 bit instance?

Comment: nvm, its just 23.23.205.241:8080. Thant works, that you for your help